# Maven "scanning for projects...." freezes, stuck, never ending... It can not write out even the next info line ( ------ )

Tags: java, maven

It is just a mvn clean install. 
It deletes the .jar file, but it cannot create again. Where can I found the bug? Or is it a nown issue?

```
INFO: call "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\java\maven\bin\mvn" clean install 
INFO: [INFO] Scanning for projects...
INFO: [INFO]
```

and that's all. No warning, no fault code, no error.

Comment: Try switching on [verbose](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/application_development/9781785286124/8/ch08lvl1sec82/controlling-the-verbosity-of-the-maven-output).

Comment: I tried -X.  
INFO: call "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\java\maven\bin\mvn" clean install -X 
INFO: Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 14:51:28+0100)
INFO: Maven home: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\java\maven

Comment: If you're going to use the "-X", then is should go after the "mvn" command, not at the end - like `mvn -X clean install`

Comment: Is this maven installation something that came with NetBeans? You may try installing the latest maven from scratch and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: Which command are you EXACTLY using? 
For how long did you left it working ? 
,...
did you tried it manually from cmd line? What was the output ?

Comment: mvn -X clean install. Same output.

Comment: @user2287094 you need `mvn clean install -X` as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Might be just that the JVM is short on memory.

```
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx2G
```

and re-run works for me sometimes with this problem. (set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx2G on Windows)